# How to click and launch an application in "background"?

Tags: gnome, xorg, launcher, tweak

I'm not sure I'm using the good words : I'd like my applications (Firefox, LibreOffice for instance) not to go foreground and capture the focus when I'm launching them (typically with a click on the launcher of the application -on the desktop, on the Dock, by "System" keyboard search ...-).

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10, classic, with Gnome. I presume, if it exists, it can be a parameter, by I did not find anything in the Settings panel nor in the Ubuntu Tweak application.

What could be done to achieve such behavior ?

Regards

Comment: Why the Unity tag if you use Gnome Desktop? This is quite misleading. Fortunatelly, you are clear about this in your question.

Comment: Sure @vanadium, thx for the remark : I confused Unity as the "usual" desktop of Ubuntu whereas they changed for Gnome years ago (and I even used the Gnome tag without noticing the opposition :-$). Unity tag removed.

Comment: Hi, I have tried custom launchers (ending with '&' at the end of the execute command), it doesn't work. I've heard about devilspie, but I'd like a command line trick, rather than adding a service at startup. Gdonf-editor doesn't provide the solution either. Any possibility to do that?

Comment: Feel free to add the information of what you tried thus far to the question (use edit). Comments are only there to improve questions/answers, and may disappear anytime.